# MapServer propertyname=fieldname only works when using gml as output

Tags: geojson, wfs, mapserver

Is it possible to make the WFS propertyname work for MapServer GeoJSON outputformat too?

Example:

curl "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=$MAP&SERVICE=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typenames=lines&count=2&outputformat=geojson&propertyname=myid"

Comment: I believe that there is nothing that a user can do. I suggest to contact MapServer developers and experienced users through the mapserver-users mailing list.

Comment: Did you define GeoJSON as an output format for the WFS?

Comment: yes else i wouldn't get a complete geojson output with all properties included instead of only the once i need using propertyname as gml does